# search and repeat cities with ng-repeat and openweathermap api

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, jsonp, openweathermap

Hi guys I've been trying for a while now to sort data braught from openweathermap.org using the api provided by the site and the ng-repeat feature in angularjs. for some reason i can't seem to get it to work... what I'm trying to do is to first display all of the gathered data and then sort it using the input field.

**Javascript**

```js
var app = angular.module('weatherApp', []);

app.controller('weatherController', function($scope, $http) {

$http.jsonp('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather', { params : {
 q : $scope.city,
 units : $scope.units,
 callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK',
 APPID: $scope.id
}}).success(function(data){
 $scope.data = data;
});
 
$scope.units = 'metric';
$scope.id = 'e08f9689f06c1b6eddb44396c749eb54';  

$scope.reset = function(){
return $scope.city = "";
};
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="weatherApp" ng-controller="weatherController">
<input ng-model="city.name" placeholder="City" />
<button ng-click="reset()">Reset</button>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat=" x in data | filter : city">
        {{x.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what do you want to display initially? all cities?

Comment: yes, initially... and then specify the result with input. something like: L gives los angeles, lofoten and so on, and los gives los angeles but not lofoten... I'm very new to this openweathermap business so aren't exactly sure how to use it. I have no problem treating a local json file the same way

Comment: For displaying cities why you are calling the openweather api?

Comment: because I  eventually also want to be able to show temperature and windspeed.

Comment: Did your try <li ng-repeat="x in data | orderBy:city">{{x.city}}</li> ?

Comment: @insomiac i dont think he has cities in that response

Comment: When you said "then sort it using the input field" did you mean to say " then filter it using the input field."?

Comment: @BuzzLajtjer this would be useful http://w4.matthiaslienau.de/angular-openweather-app/app/#/forecast

Comment: YEs,  the API just returns one json.. not cities.. Please checkout this link : 

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=bd82977b86bf27fb59a04b61b657fb6f

as well as the property name is "name" and not "city"

Comment: so it's impossible to desplay a list of input-matching options this way? Thank you guys for all your answers and help btw :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set the `$scope.id` and `$scope.units` before calling `$http.jsonp`. Seems to me that the values are used in the parameters before being set. Try changing this to:

```
var app = angular.module('weatherApp', []);

app.controller('weatherController', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.units = 'metric';
    $scope.id = 'e08f9689f06c1b6eddb44396c749eb54';  

    $http.jsonp('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather', { params : {
        q : $scope.city,
        units : $scope.units,
        callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK',
        APPID: $scope.id
    }}).success(function(data){
        $scope.data = data;
    });

    $scope.reset = function(){
        $scope.city = '';
    };
});
```